# Client-accessible noSql database?

Tags: angularjs, nosql

Im building a simple angular application and there is a small administrator panel for updating the content (a .json document). I'm looking for a way to edit the json document from the administrator panel.

I can manipulate the memory-loaded json but I can't save it. Is there a way to put the json file in some kind of cloud database and connect to it without setting up a server or backend for my application?

I want my application to be easily deployable on any ftp so I can't setup a nodeserver or install something like couchdb.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you should checkout *Firebase* - https://www.firebase.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a provider like Parse. It's free (up to a limit of requests/month), has a nice JavaScript SDK that would get you up and running quickly. https://parse.com/

Also, check out this query builder to aid in retrieving your data from Parse. It's built as an Angular service for easy integration. https://github.com/dpollot/parse-query

**EDIT**

Parse also offers hosting, for free.